# post json with file_get_contents

Tags: php, postman, file-get-contents

before trying to create the script, I tried first using the postman application, and all went smoothly without any constraint, but after I use the script I have made, the result is not the same as given by the application postman.

this is the result of the postman app
[image: this is the result of the postman app]

and this is the result of the output obtained from the postman
[image: and this is the result of the output obtained from the postman]

and then, I try to use the script I have created, as below

```
<?php
$postdata = http_build_query(
array (
  'question' => 'this is questions',
  'questionMedia' => '',
  'choices' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'text' => '123123123',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'text' => 'qweqweqwe',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'text' => 'asdasdasd',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'text' => 'zxczxczxcxc',
    ),
  ),
  'allowMultiChoice' => false,
  'endDate' => NULL,
  'enableCaptcha' => false,
  'hideResults' => false,
  'restriction' => 'ip',
)
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata,
        'header'  => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36\r\n'
    )   
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.polltab.com/api/poll/create', false, $context);
echo $result;
?>
```

but, from the script above, produces the output as shown below.

This Is the result of the output obtained from the script
[image: This Is the result of the output obtained from the script]

Comment: Try changing `http_build_query` to `json_encode`

Comment: it's not work :(